# How to delete shadowstorage for volume?

Tags: windows, volume-shadow-copy, vss, shadow-copy

`vssadmin list shadowstorage` show which volumes created shadowstorage, I want delete it for some volumes, `vssadmin delete shadowstorage` available on windows server 2008 r2, but not exists on 2019 any more, so How to delete shadowstorage?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/cc785461(v=ws.11)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/vssadmin

Comment: [vssadmin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/vssadmin) most definitely is available on Windows Server 2019.

Comment: Can you show evidence of what you claim, that this didn't exist on 2019? The second link you included says it is on 2019.

Comment: @music2myear Sorry to arbitrary, I tried, the 2019 do have `vssadmin delete shadowstorage`, the doc misleads me.

Comment: @Ramhound It is, the doc misleads me, Thank you.

Comment: @ahdung - You looked at an old version of the documentation…

Comment: @Ramhound Nope, right now the second doc is still incomplete.

Comment: “Applies to: Windows Server 2022, Windows Server 2019, Windows 10, Windows 8.1, Windows Server 2016, Windows Server 2012 R2, Windows Server 2012, Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows Server 2008” - Seems complete to me

Comment: @Ramhound Not the list of applies to, but the content, no "vssadmin delete shadowstorage" command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying, there is a `vssadmin delete shadowstorage` command in Windows Server 2019, the second document is wrong.